# Add url routing for some Redux state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a React + Redux web app that currently has no url routing.

I'd like to add it but so far everything that I've seen somehow changes the action dispatches to url changes and I'd like to change the url only for some of the actions.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use [React-Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/) for your routing, there are libraries, such as [Connected-React-Router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router), to maintain the location as state in your Redux store and to dispatch actions to change the URL only when you need it.